# Where Went My Empty Nest?

Tags: questions, auxiliary-verbs

> Where Went My Empty Nest?

Why does this question have no auxiliary verb?

Is this question grammatically incorrect?

[The phrase is used as title of a [New York Times' article]](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/08/18/opinion/parenting-children-home.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The structure is archaic, and of limited acceptability in the present day outside of very formal or literary usage, as with forgoing *do*-support in general:

> Built you this?
>
> I know not.
>
> Judge him not.

Although *do*-support is attested all the way from Old English, its adoption in questions, imperatives, and negations [accelerated](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f2ba/cbc5eca1a5ac80167e161e187436e9770635.pdf) in Early Modern English—even [within the span](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/189392/1/zep00025_030.pdf) of William Shakespeare's career. By the start of the 17th century, its [various uses](https://www.ling.upenn.edu/~kroch/papers/nels30.pdf) had thoroughly displaced the older forms.

This is largely outside the scope of ELL.SE, but I bring it up to point out that many important works of English literature such as the works of Shakespeare and his contemporaries like Marlowe and Jonson, or the King James Bible, thus predate the widespread adoption of *do*-support. A reader with exposure to early modern English should understand it, even if recognizing it as unusual, and perhaps associate it with the language of a nursery rhyme, or fairy tale, or religious texts. Besides, the more mundane *Where Did My Empty Nest Go?* also (in my personal opinion) sounds derivative or evocative of any number of popular culture works (e.g. "Where Do Broken Hearts Go?" "Where Did Our Love Go?"), which perhaps the author or editor may have wished to avoid.